# Configure Nginx global error page

Tags: nginx, errordocument

Is it possible to configure globally only the `http` part of `nginx.conf` to have all sites using the same error pages, without having to add some lines to each of the sites?

I'm *not* talking about the error page configuration *per site*.
Also not talking about having the same error page shared among multiple/all sites, using aliases.

The problem with these solutions is that it requires a configuration setup per site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [nginx documentation](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#error_page) `error_page` directive is allowed in following locations: http, server, location, if in location.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How do you declare default error pages in the `http` section?

Comment: The same as in a `server` section.

Comment: @mgorven - it's not the same. If you put error_page 404 [absolute path to 404 page]; it does not work. And you can't use location directly in http context. So far I haven't found a way to solve this.