# Nginx Global Error Page

Tags: nginx

I see this question was also asked here: [Configure Nginx global error page](https://serverfault.com/questions/275114/configure-nginx-global-error-page) but there wasn't a suitable answer.

I am currently allowing only certain IPs addresses to some of my sites and would like Nginx to drop connections from the rest of the IP addresses instead of returning a 403.  Ideally, I would like to do this without configuring each site separately.

I have this in the `http` section:

```
error_page 403 =444;
```

But, now, it tries to serve up the page =444 instead of returning a 444.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you can do a few things

```
error_page   403  http://example.com/forbidden.html;
```

Or you can do something like

```
error_page 403 /403.html

location /403.html {
    root /some/path/that/has/file; 
}
```

for the 403.html would be in /some/path/that/has/file

Comment: I would have to add that location block to all of my server blocks, correct? I'm trying to avoid having to edit every one of the server blocks since there are so many.  Thanks!

Comment: if you do the location {} option yes.. if you do the one above it that can go in the http {} but I believe it redirects.

Comment: Ok, makes sense; thanks for the explanation.  I can't get the second option to work, though.  For some reason, Nginx tries to look for /some/path/that/has/file/403.html/index.html and then fails since 403.html is not a directory.  Any suggestions?

Comment: edit your post and show that part of the config

Comment: I just did more research and, originally I was trying to return a blank page to achieve the result, but I found I can return a 444. Now my question becomes, how do I return a 444 when an IP address is denied?

Comment: check out http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#error_page there is a section for changing response code

Comment: Nevermind, fixed it.  Had a bad rewrite rule in the config. Thanks!